# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe' - Long ffmpeg code

Tags: ffmpeg

this its my code which its pretty long.
Can you tell me please why its not working ?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 - filter_complex \
   "[0:v]split=4[v0][v1][v2][v3]; \
    [v0]trim=start_frame=0:end_frame=1,loop=90:1:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[0v]; \
    [v1]trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=301,loop=90:1:299,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[1v]; \
    [v2]trim=start_frame=301:end_frame=601,loop=90:1:299,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[2v]; \
    [v3]trim=start_frame=601:end_frame=900,loop=90:1:298,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[3v]; \
    aevalsrc=0:d=3[0a]; \
    [0:a]asplit=3[a1][a2][a3]; \
    [a1]atrim=0:10,asetpts=N/SR/TB[1a]; \
    [a2]atrim=10:20,asetpts=N/SR/TB[2a]; \
    [a3]atrim=20:30,asetpts=N/SR/TB[3a]; \
    [0v][0a][1v][1a][2v][2a][3v][3a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
   -map "[v]" -map "[a]" outva.mp4
```

I get this : Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space between `-` and `filter_complex`. Remove it.

---

Corrected it in my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1071524/114058) at SU.

Comment: if I do from this - filter_complex to -filter_complex , I get this : No such filter: '"'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: @I.Alex Works for me. You'll need to edit your question with the new command and the complete console output from the command.

Comment: If I copy the code how it its, I have a bounch of errors : http://i.imgur.com/fX1pJB4.jpg , Can't figure it out how it works on you guys.

Comment: The entire command is supposed to be in a single line. Remove the `\` from the end of each line. It's presented this way at SO so that the entire command can be seen at once.

Comment: The code its this now : https://paste.ofcode.org/34qFcau495zqyS9gHPZLhqf and the error : http://i.imgur.com/sL58euA.jpg , I'm sorry but can't figure it out what I do wrong.. I'm not that good with ffmpeg.

Comment: Sorry, SO ate the character backslash from my comment above. Not supposed to remove the quotes, but the backslash --> \

Comment: It finally worked, but the process its so slow and it mess with my audio.. but I will accept your answer and thank you for your help.

Comment: The command is meant for a 30 fps video. You have to adjust the values if the video is a different frame rate.

Comment: ahh, yes it worked with 30 fps but only for 0:42, I guess I have to make such a long command for a 21:00 video ?

Comment: You can try the script that slhck wrote. Link at https://superuser.com/a/1196588/114058